# Test if TextBox Exists C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, testing, textbox, exists

I would like to test if a `TextBox` created earlier in the code exists. This `TextBox` is created in a "if test", this is why I want to test if it exists. But I don't know how I can test if it exists because I can't call the `TextBox` name because it doesn't exists..

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (((ComboBoxItem)typeproduit.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Isolant")
            {
                TextBox EpIsolant = new TextBox
                {
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 29,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Margin = new Thickness(209, 294, 0, 0)
                };
                MyPage.Children.Add(EpIsolant);

                Label EpIsolantLabel = new Label
                {
                    Content = "Ep isolant (mm)",
                    Width = 100,
                    Height = 29,
                    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                    Margin = new Thickness(209, 260, 0, 0)
                };
                MyPage.Children.Add(EpIsolantLabel);
            }
            else 
            {
                // I want to test it here
                // And if it exists, I want to remove it from MyPage.Children
            }
        }
```

Thanks for helping ! I couldn't find any help with Google

PS : When I try to change visibility, it's still not working:

```
private void ComboBox_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            TextBox EpIsolant = new TextBox
            {
                Width = 100,
                Height = 29,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Margin = new Thickness(209, 294, 0, 0)
            };
            MyPage.Children.Add(EpIsolant);

            Label EpIsolantLabel = new Label
            {
                Content = "Ep isolant (mm)",
                Width = 100,
                Height = 29,
                HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
                VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
                Margin = new Thickness(209, 260, 0, 0)
            };
            MyPage.Children.Add(EpIsolantLabel);
            EpIsolant.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            EpIsolantLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

            if (((ComboBoxItem)typeproduit.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() == "Isolant")
            {
                EpIsolant.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                EpIsolantLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                EpIsolant.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
                EpIsolantLabel.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you thought about just change the visibility of the text box instead of removing and adding it all the time based on your selection?

Comment: Declare the textbox outside of the method, as a "global" variable for the class?

Comment: @Fruchtzwerg Yes i tried but it's not working. Visibility.Visible works but Visibility.Hidden isn't working, I don't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already said, you could consider things such changing `Visibility` or `IsEnabled` property of `Button` to hide/disable it.

But if you want to stick with your solution, you could *take out* the variable outside the method:

```
private TextBox _epIsolant;
```

Then you can assign it a object:

```
_epIsolant = new TextBox
{
    Width = 100,
    Height = 29,
    HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top,
    Margin = new Thickness(209, 294, 0, 0)
};
```

and you can also check if it was created inside your method:

```
if(_epIsolant == null)
{
  ...
}
```